# Exponential Growth and Decay Question: A Bacteria Culture Grows with Constant Relative Growth Rate.

Tags: calculus

A Bacteria Culture Grows with Constant Relative Growth Rate. The bacteria count was 400 after 2 hours and 25,600 after 6 hours.

a) What is the relative growth rate? Express your answer as a percentage.

Using this formula $P(t)=P_0e^{kt}$

$t=time$

$k=growth\ rate$

$p_0=initial\ amount$

How do I calculate a formula with the information I have?

b) What was the initial size of the culture?

c) Find an expression for the number of bacteria after $t$ hours

d) Find the number of cells after 4.5 hours

e) Find the rate of growth after 4.5 hours

f) When the population reach 50,000?

This is a self study question. I have Calculus II next semester and really would like to have a clear method as to how to solve a problem such as this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let $t$ be the time in hours.

You know two things:

$$P(2) = P_0 e^{2k} = 400$$
$$P(6) = P_0 e^{6k} = 25600$$

This means you have two equations and two unknowns ($P_0$ and $k$). To solve for $k$, you can divide the second equation by the first:

$$\frac{P_0e^{6k}}{P_0e^{2k}}=\frac{25600}{400}$$

$$e^{4k} = 64$$

$$(e^k)^4 = 64 = 2^6$$

$$e^k = 2 \sqrt{2} = 2^{1.5}$$

$$\ln (e^k) = \ln 2^{1.5}$$

$$k = \frac{3 \ln 2}{2} \approx 1.0397$$

Now that we know the value of $k$, we can substitute it into the first of our original two equations to find the value of $P_0$:

$$P_0e^{2k}=400$$

$$P_0e^{3\ln 2} = 400$$

$$P_0 (e^{\ln 2})^3 = 400$$

$$8P_0 = 400$$

$$P_0 = 50$$

Note that $P_0$ is the same thing as $P(0)$, the bacteria count at time $t=0$ hours.

---

I think you should be able to answer all of the parts of your problem now. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

You have two equations with two unknowns. So you can calculate as a first step $k$. That is $k=\ln(P_1/P_2)/(t_1-t_2)$. 
Then you calcultate $P_0$. Then, c) you have with $k$ and $P_0$. The rest is to calculate directly.